# Dynamically generated imageview does not display images loaded using Picasso in android

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am trying to load an Image into a customized `ImageView` using `Picasso`.
The ImageView is generated dynamically. My problem is described as follows:

If I generate six imageviews dynamically, the image is set only on the sixth ImageView and nothing is displayed on the previous five ImageViews.

Can anyone tell me how to set the image on all 6 ImageVies. My code is as below:

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {

    imv = new RoundedImageView(Home.this);
    imv.setId(i);
    imv.setTag(i);
    Picasso.with(Home.this).load( url ).into(target);
    layout.addView(imv);
}

private Target target = new Target() {

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, final Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true);
        BitmapDrawable bdrawable = new BitmapDrawable(resized);
        imv.setBackground(bdrawable);
    }
```

Comment: Well, you're attempting to use one target to load 6 images into 6 different views. How would you expect that to work? A target it an arbitrary listener for a single image load. You need 6 images. Do the math. :)

Comment: Should I add 6 targets for that? Is there any way to generate targets too dynamically?

Comment: That would be one option. Doing bitmap manipulations in the load callback (which happens on the ui thread) is probably not ideal though. A better approach is using Picasso's [`Transformation`](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Transformation.html) feature. In your case that would be a one-liner, but [see here for more elaborate examples](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations). However, why reinvent the wheel if you can simple call `Picasso.with(Home.this).load( url ).resize(50, 50).into(imv)` (optionally specify a scale type too)? :)

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
Picasso.with(Home.this).load( url ).into(imv);
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question since it no longer scales the bitmap.